# INSERT INTO SQL Heredoc correct syntax

Tags: php, mysql, heredoc

I'm trying to use heredoc syntax with a INSERT INTO MySQL command, into a database.

The problem I'm facing is with the variable `$tPerson_SQLinsert`, which is a query.

Here's my code:

```
$tPerson_SQLinsert = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO tPerson (Salutation, FirstName, LastName, Tel, companyID)
    VALUES ("$Salutation", "$FirstName", "$LastName", "$Tel", "$companyID")
    SQL;
```

Well, there´s probably something wrong with that syntax.

Because I´m getting this Parse error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in F:\wamp\www\forms\personInsert.php on line 83
```

That is just that end tag of php `?>`.

What would be the correct syntax for the heredoc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It will work when you format it like so:

```
$tPerson_SQLinsert = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO tPerson (Salutation, FirstName, LastName, Tel, companyID)
    VALUES ("$Salutation", "$FirstName", "$LastName", "$Tel", "$companyID")
SQL;
```

I.e. the final delimiter should start in column 1.

See docs (in the warning block):
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc